# List items from 3 different tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables structure and trying to make a report from these:

___BillableDatas

```
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_Date   |BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | BIL_Status |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
|      1 | 2018-03-01 |     105 |            2 | notcharged |
|      2 | 2018-03-02 |     115 |            2 |    charged |
|      3 | 2018-03-03 |     105 |            1 | notcharged |
|      4 | 2018-03-04 |     105 |            1 | notcharged |
|      5 | 2018-03-05 |     105 |            3 | notcharged |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 |        Tax 1 |      5.000 |
|      9 |        Tax 2 |     15.000 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

*STX_Amount is a percentage.*

___ApplicableTaxes

```
|-----------|-----------|
| ATX_BILId | ATX_STXId |
|-----------|-----------|
|         1 |         8 |
|         1 |         9 |
|         2 |         9 |
|         3 |         9 |
|         4 |         9 |
|         5 |         9 |
|-----------|-----------|
```

- ATX_BILId is the item ID link with ___BillableDatas.
- ATX_STXId is the tax ID link with ___SalesTaxes.

---

So mething like this:

```
|------------|--------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| BIL_Date   | STX_TaxeName | BIL_Rate   | STX_Amount | STX_Total |
|------------|--------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| 2018-03-01 |        Tax 1 |    210.00  |      5.000 |     10.50 |
| 2018-03-01 |        Tax 2 |    210.00  |     15.000 |     31.50 |
| 2018-03-03 |        Tax 2 |    105.00  |     15.000 |     15.75 |
| 2018-03-04 |        Tax 2 |    105.00  |     15.000 |     15.75 |
| 2018-03-05 |        Tax 2 |    315.00  |     15.000 |     47.25 |
|------------|--------------|------------|------------|-----------|
```

*I do not want item with status : **charged***

---

Explications on the totals:

- `STX_TaxeName` is the name of the concerning tax from ___SalesTaxes.
- `BIL_Rate` is the `BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity` from ___BillableDatas.
- `STX_Amount` is the tax percentage from ___SalesTaxes.
- `STX_Total` is the calculated percentage from `BIL_Rate`. (`BIL_Rate*STX_Amount/100`).

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT BIL_Status
    , SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity) BIL_Rate
    , IFNULL(SUM((BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)+(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity*total_sales_tax/100)), SUM(BIL_Rate*BIL_Quantity)) STX_Total 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT b.*
            , SUM(t.STX_Amount) total_sales_tax
            , STX_TaxeName
            , STX_Amount
        FROM ___BillableDatas b 
        LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt 
            ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
        LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes t 
            ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
        GROUP  
            BY ATX_BILId
     ) x
WHERE BIL_Status = 'notcharged'
ORDER 
    BY BIL_Date DESC    
GROUP 
    BY BIL_Status
```

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bb244/11

Thanks.

Comment: Can you state what is not yet working with the given query?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I do not have the list per day and the sum aren't the good one. Also, in the third column, it's not the calculated tax amount that appears.

Comment: Are you going for a record for the number of submissions?

Comment: Your `GROUP BY`  is not even a valid statement.  Query won't run.  Fix your `GROUP BY` first, then fix your query.

Comment: @Eric, good point. Question update. `ORDER BY BIL_Date DESC GROUP BY BIL_Status`. But the query is now in error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bb244/11.

Comment: @Ross Your error is caused by `GROUP BY` after `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just do it with a simple `JOIN`?

```
SELECT BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName, BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity AS NewRate, STX_Amount
  , BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity * STX_Amount / 100 AS Total
FROM ___BillableDatas b 
JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
JOIN ___SalesTaxes t ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
WHERE BIL_Status = 'notcharged' 
ORDER BY BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName
```

Updated query with `GROUP BY`from your sqlfiddle:

```
SELECT 
    BIL_Date
    , STX_Id
    , STX_TaxeName
    , SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) AS NewRate
    , STX_Amount
    , SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity * STX_Amount / 100) AS Total
FROM ___BillableDatas b 
    JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
    JOIN ___SalesTaxes t ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
WHERE BIL_Status != 'cancelled' 
AND BIL_Date between "2018-03-01" AND "2018-03-31"
GROUP BY BIL_Date, STX_Id, STX_TaxeName, STX_Amount
ORDER BY BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName
```

Comment: Looks working. Give me few minutes to fully test it please. Thanks.

Comment: After few tries, the query doesn't work. Sorry. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41166/1. If I add a new element for a existing date, the query don't take this new element. I added `(2, '2018-03-01', '30.00', 2, 'notcharged'),` but the sum for 2018-03-01 stays at 210, whereas it should be at 270. And the taxes on right aren't updated. Do you know why please ?

Comment: My query only grabbing raw data.  You will still need to do your grouping.